# Magento ordered product name not showing in admin

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm having an issue on one of my Magento stores, but can't find out where this is going wrong. The issue is, on the Sales -> Orders -> (order id) page, the ordered items are not visible. Their prices are, including tax and status. The product name is also just available, but not in the order view.
[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r48rH.png)
Cache has been cleared several times, indexes have been rebuilt several times aswell. I've disabled all non-Zend plugins, but it still won't show.

Is anyone familiar with this issue, or can anyone point me in the right direction for where to look?

Thanks in advance.

[Magento version 1.9.2.2]

Comment: did you done any recent changes , try to use template path hints for admin and take the backup of file and replace original file.... try uninstalling some 3 party extensions and check once.....

Comment: No recent changes, I checked the template against a fresh download of 1.9.2.2, was no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the same issue and I also have not yet figured out which module breaks that. Probably we can send us a list with all our 3rd party module names, then watch out for those we have both.

However, you could work around that by editing the relevant code in `app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/view/items/renderer/default.phtml`:

Original snippet from line 34:

```
<div class="item-text">
    <?php echo $this->getColumnHtml($_item, 'name') ?>
</div>
```

Change it to:

```
<div class="item-text">
    <?php echo $_item->getName() ?>
</div>
```

*Edit:*

Alternative solution: Watch out for a layout/*.xml file which modifies the `addColumnRender` action. Removing these references can fix that, but may also break other things:

```
<adminhtml_sales_order_view>
    <reference name="order_items">
        <action method="addColumnRender">
            <column>name</column>
            <block>somemodule/someblock</block>
            <template>sales/items/column/name.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
</adminhtml_sales_order_view>
```

Comment: The module which is causing this issue was Magestore/Giftvoucher. @KingNED: Probably you have the same module running in your Magento?

Comment: This did not seem to fix the issue, nor is Magestore/Giftvoucher installed on this Magento. There are several other Magestore plugins (CustomerReward, MageNotification and RewardPoints) installed.

Comment: -- Sometimes flushing cache will solve a lot --
Thank you, this fix worked! However, this Magento installation does not use the Magestore/Giftvoucher module, it does use several other Magestore modules.